# Hermitian Conjugate Terms in Lagrangians

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, differentiation, complex-numbers

In Lagrangians (for example, that of the Standard Model) one sometimes sees $+ \text{H.c.}$ for the hermitian conjugate of a term but I am not sure what happens if there is a covariant derivative.

For example, if the term is $(\phi^{\dagger} \phi ) ( \phi^{\dagger} i D_{\mu} \phi )$ for $\phi$ a scalar field, is the Hermitian conjugate of that term meant to be $-(\phi \phi^{\dagger})(\phi i D_{\mu} \phi^{\dagger})$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the transposition requirement implicit in the definition of $^\dagger$ , beyond complex conjugation? Show your work.

Comment: Do you mean that we have have to use transpose of $AB$ equals transpose of $B$ times transpose of $A$?  So for example $(\phi^{\dagger} i D_{\mu} \phi)^{\dagger} =  (( i D_{\mu} \phi)^{\dagger} \phi ) $?

Comment: Yes, that is a start. Start with ordinary derivatives and recall integration by parts. Only *then* consider the gauge-field term...

Comment: Thanks I will do this, but is the general form of the term correct as I wrote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Hermitian conjugation,
$$
\phi^{\dagger} \phi  \mapsto \phi^{\dagger} \phi  ,\implies \\
i\phi^{\dagger} \partial_\mu \phi \mapsto  i\phi^{\dagger} \partial_\mu \phi -i\partial_\mu ( \phi^{\dagger}\phi  ),
$$
and since the scalar $\phi^{\dagger}\phi $ commutes with everything,
$$(\phi^{\dagger} \phi ) ( \phi^{\dagger} i \partial_{\mu} \phi )\mapsto 
(\phi^{\dagger} \phi ) ( \phi^{\dagger} i \partial_{\mu} \phi )-\frac{i}{2}\partial_\mu \left ( ( \phi^{\dagger}\phi  )^2\right ),  
$$
The last term being an ignorable surface term under the integral.

Finally,
$$
\phi^{\dagger}  A_\mu\cdot T ~\phi \mapsto  \phi^{\dagger}  A_\mu\cdot T ~\phi ,
$$
confirming the Hermiticity of $(\phi^{\dagger} \phi ) ( \phi^{\dagger} i D_{\mu} \phi )$.

Comment: Does this argument also imply that $i \phi^{\dagger} \partial_{\mu} \phi$ is Hermitian as well?

Comment: "Virtually", keeping in mind the total-divergence/surface term. You know how to write down its hermitian and antihermitean pieces...

Comment: ... $A= {A+ A^\dagger \over 2} +  {A- A^\dagger \over 2} $.